# Determine program segments (HEADER, TEXT, CONST, etc...) at run time

Tags: cocoa, xcode, assembly, reverse-engineering

So i realize I can open a binary up in IDA Pro and determine where the segments start/stop.  Is it possible to determine this at run-time in Cocoa?

I'm assuming there are some c-level library functions that enable this, I poked around in the mach headers but couldn't find much :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have no experience with the framework you have mentioned so I don't better post this as an answer but as far as I know the segments are determined by headers in the executable file itself. if you want to find out these information in run-time I think usual fuctions for reading files should be suficient, just get yourself some specification for executable file format you are using so you know what does which byte mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cocoa doesn’t include classes for handling Mach-O files. You need to use the Mach-O functions provided by the system. You were right in read the Mach-O headers.

I’ve coded a small program that accepts as input a Mach-O file name and dumps information about its segments. Note that this program deals with thin files (i.e., not fat/universal) for the x86_64 architecture only.

Note that **I’m also not checking every operation and whether the file is a correctly formed Mach-O file.** Doing the appropriate checks are left as an exercise to the reader.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <mach-o/loader.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int fd;
    struct stat stat_buf;
    size_t size;

    char *addr = NULL;
    struct mach_header_64 *mh;
    struct load_command *lc;
    struct segment_command_64 *sc;

    // Open the file and get its size
    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    fstat(fd, &stat_buf);
    size = stat_buf.st_size;

    // Map the file to memory
    addr = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_FILE | MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);

    // The first bytes of a Mach-O file comprise its header
    mh = (struct mach_header_64 *)addr;

    // Load commands follow the header
    addr += sizeof(struct mach_header_64);

    printf("There are %d load commands\n", mh->ncmds);

    for (int i = 0; i < mh->ncmds; i++) {
        lc = (struct load_command *)addr;

        if (lc->cmdsize == 0) continue;

        // If the load command is a (64-bit) segment,
        // print information about the segment
        if (lc->cmd == LC_SEGMENT_64) {
            sc = (struct segment_command_64 *)addr;
            printf("Segment %s\n\t"
                "vmaddr 0x%llx\n\t"
                "vmsize 0x%llx\n\t"
                "fileoff %llu\n\t"
                "filesize %llu\n",
                sc->segname,
                sc->vmaddr,
                sc->vmsize,
                sc->fileoff,
                sc->filesize);
        }

        // Advance to the next load command    
        addr += lc->cmdsize;
    }

    printf("\nDone.\n");

    munmap(addr, size);
    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

You need to compile this program for x86_64 bit only and run it against a x86_64 Mach-O binary. For instance, assuming you’ve saved this program as test.c:

```
$ clang test.c -arch x86_64 -o test
$ ./test ./test
There are 11 load commands
Segment __PAGEZERO
    vmaddr 0x0
    vmsize 0x100000000
    fileoff 0
    filesize 0
Segment __TEXT
    vmaddr 0x100000000
    vmsize 0x1000
    fileoff 0
    filesize 4096
Segment __DATA
    vmaddr 0x100001000
    vmsize 0x1000
    fileoff 4096
    filesize 4096
Segment __LINKEDIT
    vmaddr 0x100002000
    vmsize 0x1000
    fileoff 8192
    filesize 624

Done.
```

If you want more examples on how to read Mach-O files, [cctools on Apple’s Open Source Web site](http://opensource.apple.com/source/cctools/cctools-750/) is probably your best bet. You’ll also want to read the [Mac OS X ABI Mach-O File Format Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html) as well.